# Javascript date in specified timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I have a Unix timestamp and I'd like to create Date object in Europe/Paris TZ. Is there any simple way to do that (Opera, Chrome and FF supported)?

```
var stamp = 1470565421;
var date = new Date(stamp * 1000);
date = date.toParisTZ(); // convert TZ
```

Comment: If using external library is not an issue you can use Moment.js.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript